# Cambiar visbilidad de un elemento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de clicar en un div y al clicar que aparezca el contenido de otro div de esta manera y no hace nada.

```
    $(".chat").click(function(){
         document.getElementsById('contenedor_chat').style.visibility = 'visible';
    });
```

Siendo `contenedor_chat` el `hidden` y la clase `chat` son los div de cada grupo de conversacion.

Comment: Tu código parece funcionar, pero tienes un error en la función `getElementsById`. Es `getElementById` ("Element" es singular, porque solo debería haber un elemento con cada ID).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código que tienes debería funcionar, pero el nombre de la función es [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Es "Element", no "Elements".

Solo debería haber un elemento con cada ID, así por eso es "Element" en singular.

```js
$(".chat").click(() => {
  document.getElementById('contenedor_chat').style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

```css
.chat {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#contenedor_chat {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">
  <div id="contenedor_chat"></div>
</div>
```